# How do I use OR condition in payload of POST request?

Tags: python, rest, eve

I am using `Python-Eve REST API` and I want to read using `POST`. I want to use `OR` condition in my query payload like :

```
{"id":1 or "id":2}.
```

So that I will get all response with `id = 1` or those with `id = 2`.

I am using SQLALCHEMY as my database.

Comment: by [rest api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URL_and_HTTP_methods) POST  is for create objects not for read.

Comment: yes. I want to send json of json. So I was using post (using custom api in python-eve). not sure if it is possible to query with json of json in GET.
My query payload is something like:
{"myids":{"id":1}}

so somthing like:
{"myids":{"id":1} or "myids":{"id":2}}

Comment: We don't know the internal implementation of your API, so this isn't answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use list as a value of that key, it makes easy for you with python lists.

`payload = { 
   "id": [1, 2]
   ...
 }`

If the case if that any of the 'id'  is zero or NoneType, you can use this condition.

```
variable_1 = None
variable_1 = 3

payload = {
  "id": variable_1 or variable2
}

#payload becomes like this 

payload = {
  "id": 3
}
```

Comment: `variable_1 or variable2` evaluates to a Truthy value. Not queries both elements

Answer (score 0):

you can use $in in where clause in get request:

```
?where={"id":{"$in":["1", "2"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Mongo Backend, look at the Mongo Query documentation

You can try a **GET** request to query values

```
http://app/values?where={ id: { $in: [1, 2] } }
```